# Functional convergence in $W^{s,p}(M)$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

> Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian $N$-manifold . Let $s\in(0,1)$ and
> $p\in(1,\infty)$ . Define $(u_n)$ a bounded sequence in $W^{s,p}(M)$ . I
> want to verify following statements (up to some subsequence) :
>
> $(a)$ $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ weakly as $n\to\infty$ in $W^{s,p}(M)$ .
>
> $(b)$ $\displaystyle\iint_{M\times M}\frac{|u_n(x)-u_n(y)|^{p-2}(u_n(x)-u_n(y))}{(d_g(x,y))^{N+ps}}\rightharpoonup\iint_{M\times M}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^{p-2}(u(x)-u(y))}{(d_g(x,y))^{N+ps}}$ weakly as
> $n\to\infty$ in $(L^p(M))'$ .

$(a)$ is evident since $W^{s,p}(M)$ is reflexive . For $(b)$ it is evident that $$U_n:=\frac{|u_n(x)-u_n(y)|^{p-2}(u_n(x)-u_n(y))}{(d_g(x,y))^{\frac{N+ps}{p'}}}\in L^{p'}(M\times M)$$ for $p'=\frac{p}{p-1}$ , hence bounded . Therefore $U_n\rightharpoonup U\in L^{p'}(M\times M)$ weakly. Now I have a problem to show explicitly that $$U=\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^{p-2}(u(x)-u(y))}{(d_g(x,y))^{\frac{N+ps}{p'}}}$$ Moreover, if we are able to show this, is it enough to conclude the convergence of the functional as in $(b)$ ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Two things are sloppy in this question. First, you should specify that $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ means that *there is a subsequence* of $u_n$ that converges weakly to $u$. The second sloppiness is worse. Those integrals you write, without specifying the volume elements, what are they? Are they numbers or functions? Because if they are numbers, meaning that $x$ and $y$ are variables of integration, what does it mean for a number to converge weakly?

Comment: Yes, I mean convergence up to a subsequence of $u_n$. For the second one, I mean the convergence in the dual space, i.e. if we consider the functional $I:W^{s,p}(M)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $\displaystyle I(u_n)=\iint_{M\times M}\frac{|u_n(x)-u_n(y)|^p}{(d_g(x,y))^{N+ps}}d\mu_g(x)d\mu_g(y)$, then its derivative $I'(u_n)$ is a linear functional whose expression (I ignored the constant term $p$ though, since it is irrelevant) is given by the integral in the question. My question for $(b)$ is about the weak convergence of that functional.